# yii users and rights extension install on postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql, yii, yii-extensions, rights

I have installed `users and rights` extension of Yii framework and It is working properly.
I want to migrate to `postgresql`. The `rights` extension has `mysql` and `sqlite` import files (**schema.mysql.sql** and **schema.sqlite.sql** files), but It has not `postgresql` import file. 
How can I create rights and users tables in my postgresql db?
should I create the tables by hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the tables by hand and It worked properly, but I needed to exchange some code under `protected/modules/rights/components/RDbAuthManager.php`.
I replaced these fields in the sql queries in `RDbAuthManager` class:

```
$itemTable = $this->db->quoteTableName($this->itemTable);
$rightsTable = $this->db->quoteTableName($this->rightsTable);
$assignmentTable = $this->db->quoteTableName($this->assignmentTable);
$itemChildTable = $this->db->quoteTableName($this->itemChildTable);
```